# RTCPeerConnection API with Multiple peers

Tags: javascript, webrtc, groupchat, peer-connection

I have a complex logic code built in order to make a group chat between more than 2 peers by using RTCPeerConnection API.

The simulation of what happens exactly as follow:

Let say we have 3 peers A, B, and C,
the connections created from A to B and from A to C is normal and work correctly 
but the problem happens when B trying to connect C, that makes the connection A-C disconnected

in a technical way:
in connections, A-B and A-C `iceConnectionState` flag be completed but when B connected to C, A-C connection `iceConnectionState` flag change to disconnected then after moment change again to checking and still in this state. I do not know why this interruption happening and how can I resolve it.

I am sorry I can't put the code here because is very complex and huge

Comment: You can upload your code to an online service like https://textuploader.com/ or something more code specific like https://jsbin.com/